# Converter not working on rectangle Fill property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I bind the `Rectangle` `Fill` property on bool value (`Fill="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource rectangleFillConverter}}"`) and it throws a null exception. I checked the value of property (IsSelected) is not null. When I remove Converter from Fill property it works. Here is my code:

xaml

```
<Rectangle Width="{Binding Duration}" Height="20" Tag="{Binding .}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}" Fill="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource rectangleFillConverter}}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Shift}" MouseDown="LabelShift_MouseDown"></Rectangle>
```

Converter

```
public class RectangleControlFillConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            SolidColorBrush brush; 
            bool b= (bool)value;
            if (b)
                brush = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#5C8FFF"));
            else
                brush = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#73E34D"));

            return brush;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Static Resource

```
<converters:RectangleControlFillConverter x:Key="rectangleFillConverter"/>
```

Property

```
private bool _isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set 
            { 
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
```

ItemsControl where is rectangle and this converter works `Converter={StaticResource timeToPositionConverter}}"`

```
<ItemsControl Name="icSchedule" ItemsSource="{Binding .}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=icw}" Tag="{Binding .}" Margin="0,10,0,0"><!--Margin="3"Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Background="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White"-->
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=Start, Converter={StaticResource timeToPositionConverter}}" />
                                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Index}" />
                                    </Style>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate DataType="TimeLineEntry">
                                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
                                                <Rectangle Width="{Binding Duration}" Height="20" Tag="{Binding .}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}" Fill="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource rectangleFillConverter}}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Shift}" MouseDown="LabelShift_MouseDown"> 

                                             </Rectangle>                                     
                                        </Border>

                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </DataTemplate> 
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

This is the class on wich object is rectangle binding (icw is a list of that objects)

```
public partial class ScheduleItem
    {
        public string Shift 
        { 
            get
            {
                //string s = ((DateTime)DateFrom).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + " " + ((TimeSpan)TimeFrom).ToString() + " - " + ((DateTime)DateTo).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + " " + ((TimeSpan)TimeTo).ToString();
                String s = String.Format("{0}.{1} {2}:{3} - {4}.{5} {6}:{7}", FullDateFrom.Day, FullDateFrom.Month, FullDateFrom.Hour, FullDateFrom.Minute, FullDateTo.Day, FullDateTo.Month, FullDateTo.Hour, FullDateTo.Minute);
                return s;
            }
        }

        private DateTime FullDateFrom
        {
            get
            {
                DateTime dt = ((DateTime)DateFrom).AddHours(((TimeSpan)TimeFrom).Hours).AddMinutes(((TimeSpan)TimeFrom).Minutes);
               return dt;
            }
        }

        private DateTime FullDateTo
        {
            get
            {
                DateTime dt = ((DateTime)DateTo).AddHours(((TimeSpan)TimeTo).Hours).AddMinutes(((TimeSpan)TimeTo).Minutes);
                return dt;
            }
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get { return FullDateFrom; } }
        private int index;
        public int Index 
        { 
            get 
            {
                if (CampaignPerson != null)
                    return CampaignPerson.Index;
                else
                    return index;
            }
            set 
            {
                index = value;
            } 
        }
        public int Duration 
        { 
            get 
            { 
                TimeSpan dt = FullDateTo - FullDateFrom;

                return (dt.Days* 92) + (dt.Hours*4); 
            }
        }

        public bool IsEnabled 
        {
            get { return (FullDateFrom > DateTime.Now); }
        }

        private bool _isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set 
            { 
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
        #region setters

        partial void OnTimeFromChanged()
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("Duration");
            OnPropertyChanged("Start");
        }

        partial void OnTimeToChanged()
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("Duration");
            OnPropertyChanged("Start");
        }

        partial void OnDateFromChanged()
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("Duration");
            OnPropertyChanged("Start");
        }

        partial void OnDateToChanged()
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("Duration");
            OnPropertyChanged("Start");
        }

        #endregion



    }
```

ViewModel Class The icShedule is Binding on collection of this Class

```
public class ScheduleExtension
    {
        public ICollectionView icw {get; set;}

        public ScheduleExtension(CampaignPerson cp)
        {
            campainPerson = cp;
            scheduleItemsList.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(_scheduleItemsList_CollectionChanged);

            icw = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(scheduleItemsList);
            icw.Filter = ScheduleFilter;
        }

        private CampaignPerson _campainPerson;
        public CampaignPerson campainPerson
        {
            get { return _campainPerson; }
            set 
            { 
                _campainPerson = value;
                scheduleItemsList = new ObservableCollection<ScheduleItem>(_campainPerson.ScheduleItem.Where(p=>p.active)); 
            }
        }

        private DateTime _currentDate;
        public DateTime CurrentDate
        {
            get { return _currentDate; }
            set 
            {
                _currentDate = value;
                icw.Refresh();
                //CurrrentScheduleItemsList = new ObservableCollection<ScheduleItem>(scheduleItemsList.Where(p => p.active && ((DateTime)p.DateFrom).Month == CurrentDate.Month && ((DateTime)p.DateFrom).Year == CurrentDate.Year));

                //OnPropertyChanged("CurrentScheduleItemsList");
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ScheduleItem> scheduleItemsList;



        void _scheduleItemsList_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private bool ScheduleFilter(object item)
        {
            if (CurrentDate != null)
            {
                ScheduleItem si = item as ScheduleItem;
                return (CurrentDate.Month == ((DateTime)si.DateFrom).Month && CurrentDate.Year == ((DateTime)si.DateFrom).Year);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you paste the relevant (IsSelected) property definition? On which line is the exception thrown?

Comment: on which line it throws exception.. can you put the breakpoint in your converter convert method and debug?

Comment: I put the breakpoint in converter but doesn't trigger the breakpoint. In exception say that it break in xaml line of ractangle

Comment: Could you paste the DataContext assignment?

But still, if I understand you correctly, and the example works as long as the Fill binding is not there, then it seems like the rectangleFillConverter could be uninitialized. Could you give us more revealing view on the definition of converter resource? Where does it sit? If it's in another file, then when do you load it?

Comment: Converter is in resource xaml file where are the all my convertes and all other converters work. And when I want to open userControl where is that ItemsControl if torws a excetion.

Comment: Tag="{Binding .}" ??? Doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: @grv_9098 - {Binding .}, {Binding Path=.} and {Binding} are supposed to mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: @mcorluka - would you kindly paste the source for TimeLineEntry class? Maybe there's something I'm not seeing, but it seems that everything's in order with the code that you posted so far.

Comment: Can you show us the ViewModel (specialy the constructor) ?

Comment: like @CodeMonkey I can't see a problem. In my testing code, converter works fine, and rectangle switch color correctly

Comment: May be Rectangle is not enabled.

Comment: You don't have default constructor. Are you sure icw is created before CurrentDate is set ?

Comment: @mcorluka if nothing seams to work try [Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.style.triggers.aspx). It will also be easier to find bindingerrors :)

Comment: I do not need default constructor because I do not use him. And data is allright because ItemsControl write control right when I do not use Converter in Fill proprty of rectangle and every other binding works fine.

Comment: Just One Question..... Every thing except Converter is running perfect ??

Comment: Yes. Converter on any property in Rectangle doesnt work (trows Null Exception). But binding works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converter in rectangle still doesnt work on any property.

This is working for me `Fill="{Binding Path=CurrentColor}"`

and this change in ScheduleItem

```
 private bool _isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set 
            { 
                _isSelected = value;
                if(_isSelected)
                    CurrentColor = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#73E34D"));
                else
                    CurrentColor = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#5C8FFF"));
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentColor");
            }
        }

        private SolidColorBrush _currentColor = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#5C8FFF"));
        public SolidColorBrush CurrentColor
        {
            get { return _currentColor; }
            set { _currentColor = value; }
        }
```

Thanks guys for your time and your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `<DataTemplate DataType="TimeLineEntry">` to `<DataTemplate DataType="ScheduleItem">`. Maybe `ScheduleItem` is a `TimeLineEntry` (you posted only one part of a partial class), but try if it works.

The problem could also be caused by the way you are handling the collection. In the constructor you say:

```
icw = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(scheduleItemsList);
icw.Filter = ScheduleFilter;
```

And then in the `campainPerson` property you say:

```
scheduleItemsList = new ObservableCollection<ScheduleItem>(_campainPerson.ScheduleItem.Where(p=>p.active));
```

You have to either use the same collection object (by clearing it and adding new items), or by creating new `ICollectionView` and assigning it to `icw` (so you'd have to repeat the two lines from constructor after creating new `ObservableCollection`). Try that too.

Comment: You are right that shoud not be there (because TimeLineEntry doesn't exist)but I remove that and it still doesnt work... Thanks for help :)

Comment: But this `scheduleItemsList = new ObservableCollection<ScheduleItem>(_campainPerson.ScheduleItem.Where(p=>p.active));` is done before this`icw = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(scheduleItemsList);
icw.Filter = ScheduleFilter;` and it is done only onetime.

Comment: Ok, in that case it's not the problem. Still, it's a design flaw: the campainPerson property is public, so it can be assigned to at any time after the creation of the object, in which case it would break the state of the object.

Comment: I put `rectangleFillConverter` on place of `timeToPositionConverter` and it triggers the breakpoint in converter it dont make sense.

Comment: Just to be clear about one thing - if you replace the binding of Fill property with a static color (e.g. "#FF00FF), then it works fine, right?

Comment: yes that right, and when I use that Convertor i some other control the convertor works

Answer (score 0):

I dont think problem is from converter, even if all work fine when you remove it. This is my test app.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMTests.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVMTests"
    Background="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"
>
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:RectangleControlFillConverter x:Key="rectangleFillConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Content="toto" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource rectangleFillConverter}}" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The ViewModel

```
namespace MVVMTests
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : NotificationObject
    {
        private Boolean isSelected;

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            isSelected = true;
        }

        public Boolean IsSelected
        {
            get { return this.isSelected; }
            set
            {
                this.isSelected = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged<Boolean>(() => IsSelected);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the conveter

```
namespace MVVMTests
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(Boolean), typeof(SolidColorBrush))]
    public class RectangleControlFillConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            SolidColorBrush brush;
            bool b = (bool)value;
            if (b)
                brush = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#5C8FFF"));
            else
                brush = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#73E34D"));

            return brush;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

With this simple code, we can see that the converter is not the problem (window switch ugly blue / ugly green), and binding works fine.

That's not a solution, but that's show us the problem is elsewhere ...